# Find the second week in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, window-functions

I have data consisting of:

| CustomerID | Trans_date | Week_ISO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 01-sep-22 | 35 |
| C001 | 04-sep-22 | 35 |
| C001 | 14-sep-22 | 37 |
| C002 | 03-sep-22 | 35 |
| C002 | 01-sep-22 | 35 |
| C002 | 18-sep-22 | 37 |
| C002 | 20-sep-22 | 38 |
| C003 | 02-sep-22 | 35 |
| C003 | 28-sep-22 | 39 |
| C004 | 08-sep-22 | 36 |
| C004 | 18-sep-22 | 37 |

There's my code before:

```
create or replace view the_view as
select customerid, trans_date, 
       extract('week' from trans_date) week_iso
from the_table;
```

Next I want to find out, in what week will **CustomerID return**? it will look like this:

| CustomerID | Week_ISO | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C001 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C001 | 37 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 37 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 38 | 35 | 37 |
| C003 | 35 | 35 | 39 |
| C003 | 39 | 35 | 39 |
| C004 | 36 | 36 | 37 |
| C004 | 37 | 36 | 37 |

and lastly, so that there are no duplicates on the CustomerID, the final display is expected to be like this.

| CustomerID | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 35 | 37 |
| C002 | 35 | 37 |
| C003 | 35 | 39 |

> ((C004 didnt include because i would need who cust id who come first
> in their 1st week))

Answer (score 0):

I understand that, for each customer, you want one row with their first two *unique* weeks. This can be done with `denste_rank()` to rank the unique weeks, and then conditional aggregation to pivot:

```
select customerid,
    max(trans_week) where (rn = 1) trans_week_1,
    max(trans_week) where (rn = 2) trans_week_2
from (
    select cusomerid, 
        date_trunc('week', trans_date) trans_week,
        dense_rank() over(partition by customerid order by date_trunc('week', trans_date)) rn
    from the_table t
) t
group by customerid
```

Note that I changed the logic to *truncate* the date to week rather than converting it to an ANSI week number ; I would assume that you data may span over multiple years, and you possibly don't want the same week to be grouped over different years.

Comment: haii thankyou so much, but i got error message in "syntax error at or near "trans_week_1"'.... for tables, the only columns that exist are customerID and Trans_date, week_ISO I got from the query I have listed above. Is the error message because my table doesn't have a week column?

Comment: hiii why for query select cusomerid, 
        date_trunc('week', trans_date) trans_week,
        dense_rank() over(partition by customerid order by date_trunc('week', trans_date)) rn
    from the_table ............... the result 1 2 3 4 5? what's that means?